# how to deselect a row which I don`t need via SQLITE3

Tags: sqlite, blank-line

here is the table I have

```
-----   DATE           people   reason to be shown  zip
1       10/10/2011      a       reason1             100001
2       10/12/2011      b       reason2             100001
3       09/01/2002      c       reason2             100002
4       09/05/2003      d       reason2             100001
5       09/05/2003      d       unknown             100001
```

I want to select it as below

```
-----   reason to be shown      count
1       reason1                 1
2       reason2                 3
```

here is my query

```
query = '''
select [reason to be shown], COUNT(*) as cnt
    from nypd
    group by [reason to be shown]

'''
```

```
'''
-----   reason to be shown      count
1       reason1                 1
2       reason2                 3
3       unknown                 1
```

how can I deselect 'unknown' in the query?

Comment: Add a where clause to your query. Where reason != unknown

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to your statement:

```
select [reason to be shown], COUNT(*) as cnt
from nypd
group by [reason to be shown]
where [reason to be shown] <> 'unknown'
```

If by 'unknown' you mean that the value of the column is null, then:

```
select [reason to be shown], COUNT(*) as cnt
from nypd
group by [reason to be shown]
where [reason to be shown] is not null
```